# tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic" Not working

Tags: android

Manifest merger failed : Attribute application@usesCleartextTraffic value=(true) from AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-45
is also present at AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-45 value=(false).
Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:7:5-117 to override.

My Menifest file is

````
       android:name=".MainApplication"
       android:largeHeap="true"
       android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
       android:label="@string/app_name"
       android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
       android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
       android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
       android:usesCleartextTraffic="false"
       tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"
       tools:targetApi="28">```
````

Comment: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"  and follow this thread -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted

Answer (score 0):

In your application tag, add `tools:replace="android:usesCleartextTraffic"`
If your already have the attribute defined there, then just add it to the list by `tools:replace="previousData,android:usesCleartextTraffic"`